# node.js large number of requests throwing error

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, request

I got some troubles with my image downloader script, so I have array with images names (size around 5000 elements), and I do for cycle in its array, and for every iteration download image with requests module.

All works fine but only then I have arrays with size not bigger then 500+- elements.

If I run script with 5000+ elements, I see many errors spamed from request module(err or underfined responce object) , and finnaly all application could fails with EMPTY FILE ERROR. I think that there some async troubles cause NODE.JS didnt handles so many operation at time.

Maybe I can solve it by splitting my large 5000 size array by 300 items, and dont iterate over(and dont call fetchImage()) on the next chunck before previous chunk. Or maybe there exists more nicer way to solving my problem.?

```
products.map(function (product) {
        fetchImage(product.imageUrl,'./static/' + product.filename + '_big.', 0, 0);
        return;
    });

function fetchImage(url, localPath, index, iteration) {
    var extensions = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'bmp' , ''];

    if (iteration > 2 || index === extensions.length) { // try another extensions
        iteration++;
        if(iteration < 3) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                fetchImage(url, localPath, 0, iteration);
            }, 3000);
        }else{
            console.log('Fetching ' + url + ' failed or no image exists ');
            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    var fileExtension;

    if(extensions[index] === '' ) {
        fileExtension = extensions[0];
    }else{
        fileExtension = extensions[index];
    }

    request.get(url + extensions[index], function(err,response,body) {

        if(err || undefined === response){   // if err try after 3 sec timeout
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('Error URL : ' + url + extensions[index]);
                fetchImage(url, localPath, index, iteration);
            }, 3000);
            return;
        }else{
            if(response.statusCode === 200) {
                request(url + extensions[index])                  
                    .on('error', function(err) {
                        console.log("ERRRRRROR " + url + extensions[index] + " " + err);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            console.log('Error URL : ' + url + extensions[index]);
                            fetchImage(url, localPath, index, iteration);
                        }, 3000);
                        return;
                    })
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(localPath + fileExtension ));// write image to file

                console.log('Successfully downloaded file ' + localPath + fileExtension);
                return;
            }else {
                fetchImage(url, localPath, index + 1, iteration);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: What is the exact error messages you are seeing?

Comment: I got many messages like Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Comment: Sounds like either your network or the server's network can't handle the number/frequency of requests you are sending. Try slowing it down a bit.

Comment: maybe you can help me how i can slowing down my requests?

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack Try a request-throttling module. There are few available in NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using setTimeOut beetween each request

```
setTimeout(
            function () {
                fetchImage(imageUrl,'./static/' + filename + '_big.', 0, 0);
            },
                300 * (i + 1) // where they will each progressively wait 300 msec more each
        );
```